# biblioteca para input text com amostra de codigo

Tags: html

quero implementar um sistema de fórum em um site de programação e não estou encontrando uma biblioteca que me atenda para formatar o conteúdo deste text area que usamos para escrever nossas perguntas e respostas. Eu já vi inúmeros editores, mas eles dão opções como se fosse um editor de texto padrão como o word, e eu queria apenas algumas opções sendo necessárias citação e amostra de código e inserção de imagem. Igual oque ocorre aqui. Mas não achei nenhuma biblioteca que me dê essa amostra de código (é a função que usa este simbolo {} neste editor que estamos usando agora neste site). Alguém conhece uma lib para me indicar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/). É um textárea com freatures editáveis. Você pode deixar desde só negrito e itálico, até a possibilidade de visualizar o código html sendo gerado por trás, entre outros. Uso há algum tempo, é muito bom.

Comment: ele parece ser Otimo. Muito Obrigado.